# Javacv :: MPEG_2 video to iplimage

Tags: javacv

I'm using a Tv camera ,and a TV_TO_USB device to get video on my labtop

I want video to be used in a `javacv` program

due to some problems , I couldn't get the video instantaneously to the program (Although it worked for the internal and external webcams) , computer crashes with a blue screen

so I tried to begin recording and saving video using the software that came with the USB , which does work , and then , while recording , taking the recorded video into my `javacv` program

it worked , but after some seconds , it stops and shows the following error

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.type() == dst.type()) in cvResize, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\imgwarp.cpp, line 3927
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\imgwarp.cpp:3927: error: (-215) src.type() == dst.type() in function cvResize

    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.cvResize(Native Method)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.cvResize(opencv_imgproc.java:736)
    at returnToWork.ReturnToWork.main(ReturnToWork.java:174)
java.awt.Point[x=917,y=30]
```

VIDEOINPUT SPY MODE

```
SETUP: Looking For Capture Devices
SETUP: 0) CyberLink Webcam Splitter 
SETUP: 1) HP Webcam-50 
SETUP: 2) USB TV Device 
SETUP: 3 Device(s) found

[mpeg2video @ 0000000000238400] ac-tex damaged at 1 4
[mpeg2video @ 0000000000238400] Warning MVs not available
```

The code is :-

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    IplImage img ;

    CvCapture capture3 = cvCreateFileCapture("02_13_17_05_10.mpeg");
    final Vector v = new Vector<>() ;
    Image i  ;
    ImageIcon ic;
    JPA j1 ;
    if(!capture3.isNull())
    {
    img = cvQueryFrame(capture3);
    i = img.getBufferedImage();
    ic= new ImageIcon(i);
    j1 = new JPA(ic ,933,700);
    JFrame jf = new JFrame();
    jf.setTitle("HE");
    jf.setSize(j1.getWidth(), j1.getHeight());
    jf.setVisible(true);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jf.addMouseListener(new ForMouse());

    for(;;)
    {

        img = cvQueryFrame(capture3);


        IplImage image = IplImage.create(933, 700, 8, 3);
        //resize the image
         cvResize(img,image);
        i = image.getBufferedImage();
        ic= new ImageIcon(i);

        j1.jl.setIcon(ic);
        j1.add(j1.jl);
        jf.add(j1);
        jf.validate();




        char c = (char) cvWaitKey(15);

        if (c=='q')break;

    }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Crossposted: http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/85526-javacv-mpeg_2-video-iplimage.html

Answer (score 0):

Well ..

I found the problem and it is solved .. the problem was that " cvWaitKey(milliseconds) function Didn't work ( may be it works only for cvnamedwindow) , so the frame rate of my program was larger than the video recorded by the camera .. the problem was solved when I used  Thread.sleep(30);  instead